# Get each category id from column table with separate comma to show value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, find-in-set

I realy need help to fix this code. Actualy I want get gcm_id from table where the user selects several category from table category. An example of what I want main point is gcm_id data 
"gcm_id will show if user select category A,B,C" etc.. How do I do this in php mysql. I try FIND_IN_SET with no luck

```
uid | email          | gcm_id  | app_type | categories 

 1    demo@gmail.com xzxzxzxz    A           2,5,6
```

How get gcm_id if user have been select categories id 2,5, and 6?

the code :

```
if (!empty($cat)) {
        foreach ($cat as $key => $value) {
            $wc.="FIND_IN_SET('$value',categories) > 0 OR ";
        }
    }

    $pos = strrpos($wc, "OR");

    if ($pos !== false) {
        $wc = substr_replace($wc, "AND", $pos, strlen("OR"));
    }

    $wc.=" is_active=1";


    $q = "select * from datanotif where app_type='$type' AND $wc ";


    $r = mysqli_query($mysqli,$q);
    $users = array();
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
        $users[] = $row1;
    }

    $ids = array();
foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
    $ids[] = $value['gcm_id'];
}
```

Comment: By the way, you should normalize your tables and use a separate table to connect the users to the categories.

Comment: how the code, this code actualy for send notification item where user have been select category he want. If select category A,B,C user will send notif if in category A,B,C have new post..